# What software shall I use to control the internet at my home?

Tags: windows, security, internet, parental-control

I want to control the internet my kids using

so I can control what website they entre and videos they are watching on youtube

also, to control the time they spend online

I have a computer that is on all the time, I can use as a server and it runs Windows 11 Pro

Any idea what software I can use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use block/allow settings in Firewall to control internet access of applications.

App name: Firewall App Blocker, tiny & easy to use app (just drag & drop the applications).

https://www.sordum.org/8125/firewall-app-blocker-fab-v1-7/

To block individual sites, you can modify hosts file, add the domain you wish to block and map ip address to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0

I also use adguard dns to block system wide advertisements in both my mobile & PC.

If you find this answer useful please upvote it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Likely this will depend on which specific platforms you are currently using.  Your primary router likely already has some of this built in, where you can block specific domains, and set time-limits based on specific users.  For youtube, I might recommend enabling youtube-kids on their devices, however that isn't really foolproof, and can be really limiting in the kinds of videos they can access.  I've found that it blocks some really educational resources for my kids.  Amazon tablets have a similar feature-set (but are similarly limiting).  Microsoft Family has some more advanced parental control features.  Your "internet security" provider might also have some solutions, for this I use Norton.

Best advice I have, depending on the age of your children, is to talk with them about safe internet usage, and trust them to use it in their own best interests.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two methods, simultaneously myself

### OpenDNS

- You run a little applet on your pc that updates your ip address.
- You set its ip address as DNS(s) on your router.
- The free account allows you to tick categories off, such as porn and gambling.

### Pi-Hole

- Install PiHole on your Raspberry Pi
- Install it on your network
- Set your router's DNS to the Pi Hole
- Set Pi Hole's DNS to OpenDNS (if you wish to have both)
- Although its meant for ads, I top it up with the urls that OpenDNS misses.